With FluentAssertions, how do I do an record object comparison with different kind of types?
I am using the FluentAssertions test library to verify to complex structures. The caveat is that the values are to compare are a string versus a record containing the string.
Ergo the naïve comparison would be Equals( [string], [record] ) which fails; and should fail.
But i have told FluentAssertions/BeEquivalentTo to override the comparison behaviour.
I have replaced the record MyDomainPrimitive with a class MyDomainPrimitivel but there is not change.
The test message I receive is "Expected property complex.Id to be System.String, but found MyDomainPrimitive."
public record MyDomainPrimitive
{
    public static MyDomainPrimitive Create(string value) => new MyDomainPrimitive { Value = value };
    public string Value { get; init; } = "";
}

[Fact]
public void CanMap()
{
    var complex = new
    {
        Id = MyDomainPrimitive.Create("a"),
    };

    var simple = new
    {
        Id = "a",
    };

    complex.Should().BeEquivalentTo(simple, opt => opt
        .WithMapping<MyDomainPrimitive, string>(d => d.Value, s => s)
        .WithMapping<string, MyDomainPrimitive>(s => s, d => d.Value));
}


There is a similar question with answer using Using<> but there the two types are the same.

That's not what WithMapping is for. It maps different Flied/Property Names of Expectation-Type and Subject-Type.

Not quite there, but maybe usable while looking for a better alternative: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mlML6y

Ok, that might explain some. But exchanging the properties to compare is quite like mapping to a new property which is quite like what i do with d.Value.

Nice Fiddle! It overloads implicit casting which solves the problem. Unfortunately it is something I do not wish to do due to other reasons.

You don't have to have those implicit casts. The main point was to do the ValueType-to-string conversion manually ...

Aah. Missed that one. That is where I am presently. Which I try to avoid.
